# sqlite fetch statement

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

Good day,

I need to fetch rows from my sqlite table, but I need to pass multiple parameters. This is my statement that does not work.

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE currentuser=\"%@\" AND (belongstouser=\"%@\" OR mymsgforuser=\"%@\") ORDER BY ID ASC
```

I need it to first check for the currentuser match, then out of those matches to check for either the belongstouser or mymsgforuser matches. Is it possible to nest a sqlite statement in this fashion? I tried removing the parenthesis and that didn't work either. I also searched the sqlite documentation and could not find a solution.

Comment: Never use `stringWithFormat:` to build a query string. Properly bind values using the appropriate `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions.

Comment: Will the bind function allow me to build the query i need?

Comment: yes it is exactly what binding exists for

Comment: @heximal, can you kindly provide an example of how binding could build the query I'm attempting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see wrong SQL syntax. string constants must be quoted with single quotes (') instead of (")
And as rmaddy said, you'd better avoid stringWithFormat. Use [prepare statement](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) technique.

```
- (BOOL)_prepareStatement:(sqlite3_stmt **)statement withSQL:(const char *)sql {
    sqlite3_stmt *s = *statement;
    //caDatabase is declared as sqlite3 *caDatabase object
    if (nil == s && sqlite3_prepare_v2(caDatabase, sql, -1, &s, NULL)!= SQLITE_OK)
    {
        [self _showError];
        *statement = nil;
        return NO;
    }
    *statement = s;
    return YES;
}
- (caObjectId)existObject:(caObjectId)objId withType:(caCacheObjectType)objType libraryID:(int)aLibraryID
{
    @synchronized (self)
    {
        const char *caSQLexistObj   =  "SELECT id FROM objects WHERE objId = ? AND objType = ? AND libraryID = ?";
        if(![self _prepareStatement:&ca_existObjectStatement withSQL:caSQLexistObj]) {
            //produce some error message
            return;
        }
        sqlite3_bind_int(ca_existObjectStatement, 1, objId);
        sqlite3_bind_int(ca_existObjectStatement, 2, objType);
        sqlite3_bind_int(ca_existObjectStatement, 3, aLibraryID);

        NSInteger result = sqlite3_step(ca_existObjectStatement);
        if (result != SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            sqlite3_reset(ca_existObjectStatement);
            return caObjectIdNone;
        }
        caObjectId cacheId = sqlite3_column_int(ca_existObjectStatement, 0);
        sqlite3_reset(ca_existObjectStatement);

        return cacheId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will work on this as soon as I get back to my computer and will let you know.

Comment: What is the `caReturnIfNo` function? What is the `_prepareStatement:withSQL:` method?

Comment: Sorry, I just copypasted a piece of code from one of my projects and forgot to check its consistency. Hopefully new edition will make things cleaner.